# Dynamic function names

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to dynamically name functions, so that I can reuse the function.

I know the second piece of code doesn't work, but it illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
function loadMeta($postname){
    add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_' . $postname );

         //this doesn't work:
   function register_post_type_ . $postname() { 
       //dothis
   }
}
```

For background, I am trying to create custom post types in Wordpress with a reusable function. So I can create custom post types with a function like the one listed below.

```
$postname = 'portfolio';
loadMeta($postname);
$postname = 'news';
loadMeta($postname);
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

Comment: I don't know crapress, but if you can pass an object method then define a `__call` method in the class.

Comment: you can't, as far as I'm aware create a function within a function, you'd have to pass it around

Comment: testing confirms you can declare a function.. in a function .. that's ludicrous XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I think you can use [anonymous](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
function loadMeta($postname){
    add_action( 'init', function() use ($postname) {
...
});
```